# Angular :mat-input output firing twice on input value change

Tags: angular

I have to create a UI where number of Input items depend on the size of array. 
I am having a problem where my smart component is getting called twice on change of value of input.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tevrhb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdumb-comp%2Fdumb.component.ts

Comment: why you are  emitting event on (input).

Comment: @UnluckyAj i want to capture event on value chang ? which event should be used then ? 'change' is it. even on using change it fires twice

Comment: if you have multiple input you can use form array instead doing that.